# Proper term for 'if (object)' as a non-null test?

Tags: actionscript-3, terminology

In ActionScript 3, you can check if a value exists like this:

```
if (object) {
    trace("This object is not null, undefined, or empty!")
}
```

I frequently use this as a shorthand for `if (object != null)`

Is there a proper term for evaluating objects for null in this fashion? I suppose it's a matter of the Boolean typecasting rules for the language but I'm not sure if there's a name for the resulting syntax.

Comment: Null Coalescing?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator

Comment: `object != null` is the way to go. It is not a good idea to use a shorthand that is very error-prone (see @payam sbr's reply), just to save you 6-8 characters.

Comment: @NoxNoctis I wouldn't say it's error prone. In the 7 years I've been using ActionScript, I've never had a bug from using that short syntax to check if an *object* is null or undefined. I also can't think of any situation where I've needed to distinguish between null and undefined. In fact, I daresay it probably reduces the risk of obscure bugs that could arise from mixing up undefined and null

Comment: Well, I've done about 12 years of actionscript myself, so my opinion is based on bitter experience with huge projects where coding convention did not include this. I'm convinced, that using [conversion rules](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) to check if something is set, especially when you use dynamic typing, is a bad idea. What's more, code becomes more obscure: are you checking that something is set or whether it's just false? How do I know without investigating? Empty string and zero are just like any other values, why would one use the same logic as for null?

Comment: Anyway, answering your question, what actually happens there is [evaluation of expression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1) in the if clause (which happens to be just an identifier in your case) and *[implicit type conversion](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5)* of the result to a boolean value. I don't think there is any other term for that.

Comment: Are you satisfied with this answer? :)

Comment: @NoxNoctis Yes, based on not being able to find anything online, and the other answers not being completely relevant to the question, I don't think there is a simple term for this. As much as I'm tempted to make up a term, accept it as the answer, and hope it catches on, your commented answer seems the most accurate. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your `object` is always an actual object reference, e.g. a variable of any object type, then checking `if (object)` is a valid way to test for nulls. If it's a property of variant type, or a dynamic property that can potentially contain simple values (ints, strings etc) then the proper way to test for null will be explicit conversion, probably even with a strict type check `if (object !== null)`.

Comment: This is a valid statement and +1 from me, but please mind checking the actual question posed here. :)

Comment: Apparently the syntax is indeed named null coalescing, as stated in the first comment to the question, however proper null checking was also asked for as I read this. :)

Comment: Hmm. Where do you see coalescing here? That's just type conversion to boolean as clearly stated in the spec. I don't think we have such thing as null-coalescing in ActionScript at all, apart from being able to do something like `a = b||c` with object references. C#, for instance, has `??`, `?.` and `?[]` operators that do exactly null-coalescing.

Comment: @Vesper Null coalescing is a very specific type of conditional which I don't think fully encompasses my question. As far as I know it is a one-line operation only used for variable assignments.

Answer (score 0):

> [Like most computer languages, Ecma-script supports Boolean data types;
>   values which can be set to true or false. In addition, everything in
>   JavaScript has an inherent Boolean value, generally known as either
>   truthy or falsy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

### list of falsy values (non truthy)

- false
- 0 (zero)
- "" (empty string)
- null
- undefined
- NaN (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)

regularly for checking if a variable is null
you may use : `(a == null)` this statement returns *true* if **a** is null, **But** also return *true* for all of the above list, because they'r all *falsy* values and `(a == undefined)` returns *true*, even **a** is not undefined but null or 0 or *false*.

so you should use **Identity operator** in this case. following evaluations just returns true when **a** is null

```
(typeof a === "null")
// or
(a === null)
```

Comment: `NaN` is actually a range of numbers, which is why you can't compare two NaNs for equality (the ecma spec doesn't allow you to), and which is also why we have the `isNaN()` function.

Comment: Your answer is full of typos and poor grammar and is very difficult to read. I'm also not sure if it really addresses my question; you're explaining how various statements evaluate in ECMAScript, which is not what I asked.

Comment: @user45623 unclear questions, gives unclear answers, try asking better questions first, however a reference was posted above without any typo or grammar issue.